# Closure Compiler throws "Variable ... declared more than once" for different files

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

So far I have what I believe to be a simple setup; I have `core.js`, `signup.js`, and `login.js`, where the core is assumed to be loaded before each of `signup.js` and `login.js`, and `login.js` and `signup.js` would never be loaded on the same page at the same time.

This is the command I'm using to compile the JS files into different modules with the `--module` flag

```
java -jar ../../compilers/closure-compiler.jar \
--module core:1: --js ../../js/core.js \
--module signup:1:core: --js ../../js/signup.js \
--module login:1:core: --js ../../js/login.js \
--compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS \
--externs ../../externs/jquery-3.3.js \
--externs ../../externs\sweetalert2.js \
--externs ../../externs\grecaptcha.js
```

And each of `login.js` and `signup.js` have their own form, so I have a variable in each called `$Form` like so

```
var $Form = $('#login');
```

However running that command on my files gives the following error

```
../../js/login.js:13: ERROR - Variable $Form declared more than once. First occurrence: ../../js/signup.js
var $Form = $('#login');
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Am I doing something wrong with `--module` flag, or missing something that would indicate that these files never come in contact? Or should I get into the habit of prefacing my variables from each child/page specific JS file like naming using `$SignUp_Form` and `$Login_Form` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The module flag splits files. It does not give any indication that the files are loaded on separate pages.

Your best bet would be to either use distinct variable names, isolate the scopes using function wrappers or use either commonjs or es6 module s.

Comment: That's what I figured it must have been, which is already what I've been doing in the meantime, and how I shall continue doing so